# Particle's acceleration when it achieves maximum displacement in the +x direction

Tags: derivatives, physics

I'm not sure if this goes in the physics section or the mathematics section, but this question seems pretty math oriented, so I'll ask it here.

$t\ge0$ and $v_x=24-3t^3$

I have to find the particle's acceleration when it achieves maximum displacement in the $+x$ direction. I'm not sure how to know exactly when the particle hits maximum displacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Maximum displacement occurs at the time when the velocity reaches zero.  (Why?  You can think either from a physical perspective or a mathematical one.)

And acceleration is the derivative of the velocity with respect to time.

Can you proceed now?

Comment: Do I do $0=24-3t^3$ to find t first, and then plug it into the derivative of the velocity equation?

Comment: Yes!  It sounds as if you have it.  Well done.

Comment: The question right before this one asked what the acceleration is when the velocity first reaches zero... is this the same exact thing?

Comment: Yes.  It is the same thing.